# How to render in form view model's Many2one's field field in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, view, odoo-10

Let's say I have

```
class A(models.Model):    
    _name = "A"
    field_a = fields.Many2one('B')


class B(models.Model):
    _name = "B"
    field_b = fields.Char()
```

On a form which model is A I need to render field_b. I tried like this:

```
<field name="field_a.field_b" />
```

but with no luck

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you update your question with specific libraries you are using to achieve this?

Comment: There are no libraries, just Odoo

Comment: The correct syntax is `<field name="field_a"/>`.

Comment: it renders dropdown for the field_a, while I need field_b of that field_a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to display field from m2o in the current view create a related field.

```
class A(models.Model):    
    _name = "A"
    field_a = fields.Many2one('B')
    field_b = fields.Char(related='field_a.field_b')


class B(models.Model):
    _name = "B"
    field_b = fields.Char()
```

And now in  model A view you can just:

```xml
 <field name="field_b" />
```

Comment: There is a very [small reference in the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) that shows a real-world example, which may also be helpful.